# networkD3 sankey diagram node with no target?

Tags: r, sankey-diagram

I'm now drawing sankey diagram with networkD3 in R. 
I found all targets must go to a source. Empty/NULL target in link will raise an error. But what I trying to implement needs those goes-to-nowhere value stay where they are and link to nothing like picture below

I know I could link them to a node like 'none' node but that looks terrible on our data which has a lot of null value.

What I miss on networkD3 package? Could anybody give me hint? Thank you

[the layout of node A bar I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KaZP.png)

Comment: You're not missing anything. That is how `sankeyNetwork` is designed to work. The values that you give to the links that flow *from* each node (right side of the node) always add up to 100% of that node.

Comment: Thanks @CJYetman. I guess I have to do some work to get I want.